# sql server timeout expired processed pages

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, timeout

Getting this error when executing 3 query that automatically backup dan rar backup database file.

This error happens when running about 3-5 minutes.

> Timeout expired. Processed 10 pages for database 'DB-HO', file 'DB-HO_log' on file 2.

Other info :

1. using SQL Server 2005 on Windows Server 2003
2. using VB.net 2005 to execute that query by manually scheduled
3. this happen when executing large DB. when executing small DB is no problem at all.
4. I've already setup the timeout expired in management studio options : server -> connections -> remote query timeout = 3600 (1 hour)
5. i've already setup also the vb.net connection string with 'Connect Timeout:3600;'
6. still doesn't solve the problems

Can anyone point me where I should set this timeout things?

**update :**

Cause I've need this backup to worked. So I've changed the query into store procedure. And that solved my problem for now.

Though still I'm curios why can't I exec heavy query in vb.net side?

And what does this **timeout expired processed pages** means?

Comment: have you set timeout in command.CommandTimeout??

Comment: yes i've done that too. like in the connection string. i've added "Connect Timeout=3600;". still get the same error here....

Comment: can you please post your code over here.

Comment: hi AB Vyas, thx for the clearing the confuses of my time out problem.

Comment: have you solved issue?

Comment: Yes tq for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to set timeout in Commend like `Command.CommandTimeOut`